# i could'nt find job uuid at service M8

Tags: api, uuid, servicem8

i have to put jobs {uuid} in [https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job/{uuid}.json](https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job/%7Buuid%7D.json) for updating a job but I cannot find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list of jobs first and then find the relevant uuid for the job you want using this: https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job.json